# API performance testing connection time out

Tags: mysql, node.js, jmeter, performance-testing, restful-architecture

Currently working on the performance of my RESTFul api implemented using node js and mysql. For load testing of my APIs I'm using jmeter. So When I call my one of url for testing load with configuration

Virtual Users : 100,
Total Duration : 60s,
Time delay : 0s,
Ramup-Period : 1s

Jmeter show status OK for around 300-400 results and after that It timeouts for rest of request. Then after this I'm not able to ssh login or ping my server from my system till restart my system. Why this is happening?. Is it problem of my APIs design or server load problems.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your server simply becomes overloaded, I would suggest monitoring its baseline health metrics using [top](https://linux.die.net/man/1/top), [vmstat](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/vmstat8.html), [sar](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sar) etc during your test execution. Also consider increasing your ramp-up period setting so load would increase more gradually - this way you will be able to correlate system behavior with the increasing load and determine what is the maximum of concurrent requests your system is able to serve.

Alternatively (or in addition to top, vmstat and sar) you can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) which is capable of collecting a lot of metrics and sending them to JMeter so you will have system performance report along with the load test results. Check out [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) guide for detailed installation and configuration instructions along with usage examples.